# Including multiple .txt files into httpd.conf using regex?

Tags: regex, apache, include, httpd.conf

I want to be able to include multiple virtualhost files into httpd.conf. I know that it's possible to include one using something like:

`include virtualhost-1.txt`

However, I want to be able to import all virtualhost files within a certain directory, without needing to hardcode the include statements. Is there an appropriate command/syntax for this? I know the directory and have a suitable regular expression:

```
^.+-[0-9]+\.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the [Include directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include) is the following:

```
Include file-path|directory-path|wildcard
```

You can do for example:

```
 Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/vhosts/dom1-*.conf
```

to include all configuration starting with `dom1-` from the directory `/usr/local/apache2/conf/vhosts/`. Note that you can use wildcards but you cannnot use a full regex.